# ArcGIS Runtime: Getting different results when calculating angles between same map points in different spatial references

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis, esri

I'm developing with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for dotNet 10.2.6.

I'm trying to calculate the azimuth (degrees from the north) between two points on the map.

The map has a spatial reference 3857 (WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere) and I use spatial reference 4326 (GCS_WGS_1984) for the user display.

For northing the user POV, I let the user click his location on the map and another point on the map which he is currently looking at. I then use a simple tangance to calculate the azimuth angle between the two given points.

When I use the map spatial reference (3857), I get logical results.
When I project the two points to the user spatial reference (4326) and do the same calculation, I get a ~5 degrees error when the azimuth is around 45 degrees (same for all quadrants, i.e. 135, 225 and 315).

Example:

```
Azimuth 0:
[spatial reference Wkid=3857] dAzimuth=00.066 
x1=3910430.46448709 y1=3847292.56056299 
x2=3910431.15764925 y2=3847888.00648926
[spatial reference Wkid=4326] dAzimuth=00.079 
x1=35.1279945373535 y1=32.6375465393066 
x2=35.1280007641351 y2=32.6420507989248

Azimuth 45:
[spatial reference Wkid=3857] dAzimuth=45.002 
x1=3910430.46448709 y1=3847292.56056299 
x2=3910850.25858266 y2=3847712.32276465
[spatial reference Wkid=4326] dAzimuth=49.901 (*** ~5 degrees error ***)
x1=35.1279945373535 y1=32.6375465393066 
x2=35.1317656118759 y2=32.6407218603483
```

The distance between the points in the example is about 500m.
The angle calculation is:

```
dAzimuth = Math.Atan(dDeltaX / dDeltaY) * RADIAN_TO_DEGREE_FACTOR;
```

The projection is done with the GeometryEngine:

```
projectedPoint = GeometryEngine.Project(inputPoint, targetSpatialReference) as MapPoint;
```

What could possibly cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPSG:4326 is not really a projection, and if you look at it as a projection it is surely not conformal.

So you should not rely on that "projection" for angles, but you must rely on the Earth [bearing formulas](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get precise results.

---

So, the bearing between two points on Earth (latitude, longitude) ([R](https://cran.r-project.org/) code):

```
R> vectorBearing <- function(a_lat, a_lon, b_lat, b_lon) {
    a_phi    <- a_lat * pi / 180
    a_lambda <- a_lon * pi / 180
    b_phi    <- b_lat * pi / 180
    b_lambda <- b_lon * pi / 180
    dL <- b_lambda - a_lambda
    cosBLat <- cos(b_phi)
    Y <- cosBLat*sin(dL)
    X <- (cos(a_phi)*sin(b_phi))-(sin(a_phi)*cosBLat*cos(dL))
    atan2(Y, X) * 180 / pi                                     
}
```

Geometryically, the angle (on A) between 3 points ABC on a plane:

```
R> angleABC <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
    P12 <- sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
    P13 <- sqrt((x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2)
    P23 <- sqrt((x2-x3)^2 + (y2-y3)^2)

    if (P12==0 || P23==0 || P13 ==0) return(0)
    acos((P12**2 + P13**2 - P23**2) / (2*P12*P13) ) / pi * 180
}
```

Your specific example, using the bearing formula on latitude/longitude points gives a proper result:

```
R> vectorBearing(32.6375465393066, 35.1279945373535, 32.6407218603483, 35.1317656118759)
[1] 45.00116
```

Using the geometric formula on projected points, too:

```
R> x1<-3910430.46448709
R> y1<-3847292.56056299
R> x2<-3910430.46448709
R> y2<-4000000.00000000  # any
R> x3<-3910850.25858266
R> y3<-3847712.32276465
R> angleABC(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
[1] 45.00218
```

(The results are not exactly the same due to 1) probably some finite-arithmetic error 2) EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) is [slightly non-conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection#Properties)).

Whereas, using the planar function directly on lat/lon values:

```
R> x1<-35.1279945373535
R> y1<-32.6375465393066
R> x2<-35.1317656118759
R> y2<-40.0000000000000  # any
R> x2<-35.1279945373535
R> x3<-35.1317656118759
R> y3<-32.6407218603483
R> angleABC(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
[1] 49.90194
```

...gives the imprecise result you were seeing.

---

<sub>See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21363/6998</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The "error" may be due to differences in the projections. A geographic coordinate system (4326) and projected coordinate system (3857) are going to give different results.

See also:

- [How does one calculate an angle in a geographic coordinate system?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10279/how-does-one-calculate-an-angle-in-a-geographic-coordinate-system)
- [ArcGIS Length and Area Calculation Scenarios](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41157/arcgis-length-and-area-calculation-scenarios)